# AES, RSA, ECC Key size

Tags: encryption, aes, rsa, password-cracking, ecc

It is generally said that 2048-bit RSA keys are roughly equivalent to 112-bit symmetric keys and 2048-bit RSA keys are "sufficient for commercial use until around the year 2030" (https://security.stackexchange.com/a/65180/189448).

What is a rough estimate for when AES, RSA, and ECC keys of n bits are unsafe for amatuers?

"Unsafe" as in a tech-savvy person of medium income can decrypt a given message within 2 years.

Comment: One caveat I would add is that there's always the possibility of an exploit being found which takes the time to crack your key to a feasible time for an attacker. Like we saw today with the new TLS 1.3 vulnerability published.

Comment: @Daisetsu I'm sorry but I really don't see how the possible duplicate is a duplicate. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Daisetsu The TLS 1.3 vuln has been disclosed a few months ago. It's not really new. I'm also assuming the technology grows steadily and no sudden breakthroughs

Comment: Oh wow. I don't know what happened to that link. Totally the wrong one.

Comment: Slight correction maybe:  2048-bit RSA keys are equivalent in strength to 112-bit symmetric keys not 128-bit. See [here for source](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65174/4096-bit-rsa-encryption-keys-vs-2048/65180#comment117712_65180), via NIST I think.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of purposes, there is a website, [keylength.com](https://www.keylength.com/en/compare/), that uses various academic and private organizations mathematical formulas to approximate.

If you select 2030 you will get the results.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but these estimates are more for "safe against state actors" aren't they? I'm only looking for estimates against, say, a tech-saavy friend.

Comment: It is about the resources you have. Have a look at [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298).